# FW/1 Controller changes not updating in view

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, fw1

Way late to the party, but was messing around with FW/1 this week and I am having a problem with controllers and real time updates. I have the following code to simulate authentication for now.

application.cfc

```
public function setupRequest()  { 

    controller("user.checkAuthorization");
 }
```

user.cfc

```
function checkAuthorization(any rc) {
    rc.authenticated = true;

}
```

In my view I toggle certain things based on rc.authenticated. All of this works fine, but if I toggle rc.authenticated from true to false nothing changes on the screen until I reset the app. Then I see the updated changes on the screens.

I'm not sure why changes aren't being made on page without the app re-init. Is this something in FW/1? Something in Lucee? Commandbox etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are cached by the framework so any changes won't be reflected until you reload the cache. You can do this on an ad hoc basis by adding `?reload=true` to the URL.

If you are in a dev environment and making frequent changes to controllers you could add some logic to the `setupRequest()` method in Application.cfc to clear the contoller cache on every request:

```
public void function setupRequest(){
  if( isDevEnvironment ) // use your own way of determining this
    application[ variables.framework.applicationKey ].cache.controllers = {} // clear the controller cache on every request
}
```